# Falsecolor raster from multiple rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, color, rendering, forest-ecology

How can I combine multiple single band rasters into a falsecolor RGB background in QGIS?

I can, of course, use the multiband color renderer to select specific bands, call them A1,A2,A3 from a single raster file source A to R,G,B channels. But I have the desired bands in **different files**, so it's R=A1, G=B2, B=C1 that I need.

[image: Desired combination]

For the moment, I am creating and maintaining a monster .vrt with A1...An,B1...Bn,C1...Cn munged into one, and then using the multiband color renderer. This requires annoying editing of an XML file to add `<Description>` tags and to overcome to inability to add different `-b` switches with `-separate` in the `gdalbuiltvrt` call the QGIS `Build virtual raster...` algorithm uses. I'm hoping for a way where I could assign the **right rendering settings to each layer in the QGIS layer tree so that they would individually render as in the 3 rightmost images above, and when all 3 are checkmarked in the layer tree they would add as at left.**

I've tried using the Singleband grey renderer for each input layer and colorizing it in `Layer rendering` settings. But that keeps whites white and only shifts the midgreys. So I created my own color maps from `#00000` to `#ff0000` (etc.). But now the topmost layer wins, unless I adjust transparency in which case the color gets washed out. So I've been playing with the blending mode (e.g. `Darken` and `Screen` as opposed to `Normal`) but can't seem to get the logic right.

**This ought to be simple, so I'm probably barking up the wrong tree!**

BTW, the reason for this is exploration of different spectral bands and ratios across a time sequence of Sentinel 2 images to discover what combination of data will best pinpoint forest insect damage.

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work with your layers but I got it to work with Simple vector layers. So following vague color theory.
[image: Wikipedia RGB color theory]
I created a layer where each was a pure Red Green or Blue and had a subtract blend mode applied. First I tried the addition blend mode but this didn't work. However I found that if you create a black under layer and use the subtract blend mode they combine correctly. Without the black under layer QGIS used the map canvas color and everything is just white.
[image: QGIS RGB Subtract blend mode]

I also tried Cyan, Magentna, Yellow on a white background but that didn't give me the results I expected but might work for your files.
[image: QGIS CMY colors suntract blend mode]

Comment: This worked, thanks. Black patch as underlayer, rasters with a color ramp from black to #ff0000 / #00ff00 / #0000ff, with Subtract rendering mode.
Didn't try Cyan, Magenta, Yellow explicitly, but noted the RGB color-ramped layers in Addition rendering mode on a white background generate complementary colors, so what you describe should work too (just not necessary for me).